# Where in the DB are CiviCase timelines and sequences stored?

Tags: civicase

Please can someone tell me, where in the DB are CiviCase timelines and sequences stored?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, [`civicrm_case_type.definition`](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/4.6.9/xml/schema/Case/CaseType.xml)

If the `definition` is `NULL`, then it will fallback and search for an XML file.

The loading logic is in [`CRM_Case_XMLRepository`](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/4.6.9/CRM/Case/XMLRepository.php#L79).